# What does "prime yourself with" mean?

Tags: idioms

I do not have a context for the sentence but I need to know the **meaning** and an **example sentence**.
I cannot find it in any dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to say for sure without context.

My first guess: To "prime a pump" is to put water (or whatever fluid) into a pump to get it started. If the water level is below the mechanism of the pump, then it will just be pulling on air, so sometimes you have to put in some water to bring the level up to the blades (or whatever) so that the pump is pulling on water instead of air.

So by analogy, we say that a person is "primed" meaning that he has been prepared and is now ready to begin a task. Preparation in this sense could mean getting tools in place, learning how to do what is required, or just getting emotionally ready to do the job. Like, "The coach gave a rousing speech, and now the team is all primed and ready to go!"

Comment: From my experience, **prime** usually has an emotional quality about it.